# Ruby Map Function Returning nil

Tags: ruby

I'm  trying  to use map functionality of ruby on an array of objects.  I want to return a new array of only select fields.

```
the_array.map do |element|
    {
       "name"=> element.name,
       "field_type"=> element.field_type
    }
end
```

This is replacing the entire array with `[nil,nil,nil]`.   What am  I doing wrong?

```
 def self.select_fields(the_array)
    14:   waw =  the_array.map do |element|
    15:           {
    16:             "name"=> element.name,
    17:             "field_type"=> element.field_type
    18:           }
    19:           binding.pry
    20:         end
 => 21:   binding.pry
    22: end
```

At the second binding.pry if I print out waw I get `[nil, nil, nil]`

Comment: Your code seems to be valid. Could you show the whole example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of block execution is the last it's line. You have `binding.pry` at this line which obviously returns `nil`. That's why you get an array of `nil`s.

Just remote it and your code should work like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Remove `binding.pry` and try again

Comment: As Sergey explained: `binding.pry`s return value (`nil`) as used for the `map` operation